# Patterns for the x and y values for linear, natural log, exponential, and power

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know that the pattern for linear function is +/+ for the x and y values respectively. Basically, when you add to the x value, you add to the y value assuming it is an increasing function.

I was wondering if someone could tell we what it is for natural log, exponential and power.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is $y = -x$ a linear function?

Comment: It sounds like you might be grasping at something along the lines of "If I change the __ value by __ , how much does the __ value change?"  The full answer is discussed at great length in differential calculus.  The function $y=kx$ will be such that when $x$ increases by $1$, you'll have $y$ increase by $k$.  The function $y=k^x$ will be such that when $x$ increases by $1$, you'll have $y$ increase by a factor of $k$.  For $y=\log_k(x)$ if $x$ increases by a factor of $k$ then $y$ increases by $1$, and if $y=x^k$ then if $x$ increases by $1$ then $y$ increases by $(x+1)^k-x^k\approx kx^{k-1}$

Answer (score 1):

You are asking whether these functions are increasing. A linear function is not always increasing though. The natural log $\ln(x)$ and the exponential function $e^x$ are strictly increasing, but the function $x^2$ is not: it is decreasing on the negative axis, and increasing on the positive axis.

However, as @Eric-Towers mentioned, it is not as straight forward as you might initially think.

Comment: how about if you assume all the graphs are increasing. For example, exponential would be +/x

Comment: I don't understand? If the graph is increasing, then by definition so is the function. What does the x in +/x mean?